# Como posso diminuir o tempo de processamento do programa?

Tags: c, c++, otimização

Preciso exibir essa saída:

1 2 3 PUM
5 6 7 PUM
9 10 11 PUM
13 14 15 PUM
17 18 19 PUM
21 22 23 PUM
25 26 27 PUM

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    unsigned short int in, i = 0, j = 1, k = 0;

     scanf("%hd", &in);

    while(i < in){
        while(k < 3){
            printf("%hd ", j);
            j++;
            k++;
        }

      j += 1;
      k = 0;
      i++;
      printf("PUM\n");

     } 

return 0;
}
```

Aceito sugestões de otimização!

Comment: No caso você entrou com 28? Dá pra simplificar isto e aí provavelmente ficará + rápido.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dá para simplificar bastante, aí a performance possivelmente será melhor. O código está bem confuso e tem muita coisa desnecessária. Mas tem que medir pra ver se ficou mais rápido, tem casos que surpreende a gente. Um cálculo de resto pode ser pior do que algumas adições (para isto pode ser mais interessante usar o operador *and* que certamente é bem rápido, conforme mostra a resposta do Bacco). Usando um tipo `int` pode dar um ganho se a arquitetura for otimizada para este tipo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int in;
    scanf("%d", &in);
    for (int i = 1; i <= in; i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 0) printf("PUM\n");
        else printf("%d ", i);
    } 
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FxIpge). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vhjtnrlb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/PinGame.c).

Alternativa baseada na resposta do Leo:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int in;
    scanf("%d", &in);
    for (int i = 1; i <= in; i += 4) printf("%d %d %d PUM\n", i, i + 1, i + 2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Xxo364). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zvoizgqt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/PinGame2.c).

Answer (score 6):

Segue uma alternativa tão curta quanto a resposta do Thiago, mas que funciona com números que não são múltiplos de 4:

```
int main(){
    unsigned short int in, i;

    scanf("%hd", &in);

    for( i = 1; i <= in; i++ ) printf( i & 3 ? "%d " : "PUM\n", i );
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando com o número 10 como exemplo no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/vThWpN)**.

- A operação `i & 3` é um meio rápido de se obter os 2 bits menos significativos do contador, efetivamente retornando `0` para todos os casos onde a mensagem "PUM" deve ser exibida.
- O operador ternário vai usar `"%d "` em todos os casos em que a expressão mencionada não retornar `0`
- Mostrei o ternário como alternativa ao `if`, mas vale dizer que normalmente, se o critério é eficiência, a estrutura similar à resposta do @Maniero é mais apropriada, apesar de mais longa.

Segue o código similar ao do @Maniero trocando o operador de resto por operação de *bits*:

```
int main(){
    int in, i;
    scanf("%d", &in);
    for ( i = 1; i <= in; i++ ) {
        if (i & 3) {
            printf("%d ", i);
        } else {
            printf("PUM\n");
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Pus um demo no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/hbOcdU)** com mesmíssima lógica, mas em menos linhas.

Comment: Muito bom cara!!

Answer (score 5):

Como a variação é constante de três valores e um PUM, imprima três variáveis de uma vez e o texto (considerando que sejam sempre múltiplos de 4 e uma variação constante como apresentada no exemplo).

x y z PUM

Depois  do PUM, na próxima volta do loop, some quatro ao valor de cada variável.

Ficará mais rápido!

Answer (score 2):

**Fiz um dessa forma aqui, usando as dicas das respostas, melhorou bastante do meu primeiro código pra esse kkk**

```
 int main(){
    unsigned short int in, i = 1;

    scanf("%hd", &in);

    while(i <= in*4){
         printf("%d %d %d PUM\n", i, i + 1, i + 2);
         i+=4;
    }  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oi Thiago, ainda falta marcar uma das respostas, já que se baseou em mais de uma, selecione a que melhor te inspirou.